# get_term_link() returns incorrect url

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type (`item`) with multiple custom taxonomies (`item_category_A`, `item_category_B`, etc.) I'd like to retrieve custom taxonomy terms of the current `item` from `item_category_A`, also make them clickable. My code retrieves the correct terms, but then using `get_term_link()` retrieves a url, looking like `sitename.com/item_category_B/category_A_term_slug` . What am I doing wrong? My code looks like this:

```
function get_item_category_A(){

   $item_cat_A = get_the_terms(get_the_ID,'item_category_A');

   echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($item_cat_A[0]->slug,$item_cat_A[0]->taxonomy)).'">'.esc_html($item_cat_A[0]->name).'</a>';

}
```

Still, when I run the function, it returns the url than points to the correct term in the incorrect taxonomy (`sitename.com/item_category_B/category_A_term_slug`).

Comment: I would suggest adding the code that registers your taxonomies to your question as well.  Might be a rewrite argument askew?  Could be a few things.

Comment: It was exactly that! Thank you! Please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress allows for customization of the default URL rewrite behavior (/slug/term) with a `rewrite` arguments array passed to the `register_taxonomy()` function.

By defining values for the `slug` or `hierarchical` keys in this array, the default URL structure can be altered to suit your needs.  It may also be altered such that unexpected results are returned.

When creating multiple taxonomies, it is easy to copy & paste the labels and parameters arrays for one tax and overlook the necessity to update some of the specifics for subsequent uses.

WP Codex reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments

Hierarchical taxonomy explanation via Milo:
[How to enable hierarchical permalinks for hierarchical taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17325/how-to-enable-hierarchical-permalinks-for-hierarchical-taxonomies)